# Is this intuitive set theoretic statement valid?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a predicate P of sets. Is it true that there exists a set S that contains all sets S', such that S' contains all sets T that satisfy P?

Comment: If your predicate is $x=x$, then $S$ would have to be a set of all sets, which does not exist.

Comment: "Contains" is a dangerous term in set theory. Do you mean "superset of" or "has elements."

Comment: Technically, if the predicate is $x=x$, then $S$ would be the set of all sets that contain all sets. That is actually fine, since $S$ is empty. :) @JoeJohnson126

Comment: contains means "has elements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking whether
$$ S = \{ s' \mid s' = \{ t \mid P(t) \} \} $$
exists?

Yes it does. Proof: Either $\{t\mid P(t)\}$ exists as a set or it doesn't. If it exists, then $S$ is its singleton (which then obviously also exists). Otherwise $S$ is the empty set (which always exists).

Comment: Except the question doesn't say "exactly contains," which is tricky. The real problem in this question is clarifying the question.

Comment: I meant exactly contains.